# whereIn is returning only first value from the stored data laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i need to find membership id from stored array in database column but its take only 1st id for example
my data in membership_id column is 3,5,7 but and i user where in with array its returns only 3 the first number not middle or last.

```
$userss = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
$test = (int)$userss->membership_id;
$ppvse = Ppv::whereIn('membership_id',[3,5,7])->whereStatus(1)->count();
dd($ppvse)// returns 0 record found. and if 3  is first record then correctly 1 record found.
```

[database image table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCLjI.png)

Comment: Do all have status = 1?

Comment: yes . i even tried by removing status

Comment: And you are meaning to use count() here and not get()?

Comment: yes  want to count.

Comment: Will you post dd(Ppv::all()) please :)

Comment: `WhereIn` is not working like you expect. And your database design is bad.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tdmqlo

Comment: @u_mulder sir please can you help me issue with wherein

Comment: @u_mulder i just want to get value from data if its in array

Comment: Your database structure is wrong. You put `3,5,7` in a single field. This way is wrong for `whereIn` you can't get expected data with this method

Comment: ok thanks got it what i need to achieve that please guide me

Comment: You need to create another table for `membership_id` where you store every `member's id` and their  `ppv id`

Comment: @STA that is already achived in user table.. there is colmn with membership_id for each user. issue is i want to allow more than one membership ids to view video.  and user can subscribe 1 id only one time

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue after many hours spend because i am not an expert. so quit using where in and used like like  when  data is stored in imploded array. hope it will help someone who want to get value from array stored data

```
$ppvse = Ppv::where('membership_id','like', '%'.$test.'%')->where(status,1)->count();
```

Comment: This solution will return wrong result if we want to fetch particular '2' membership_id record while database has membership_id eg. '2, 22, 122, 1021, 2000'. 'like' solution will return all 5 records because all membership_ids have '2' keyword. Not recommend this solution. Thanks Alex.